On a MSI EX620 the internal microphone doesn't show up in the input peripherals list
I use Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. On my laptop, an MSI EX620, there is an internal microphone. But it is not listed in the input peripherals list (in sound parameters). It doesn't appear in PulseAudio neither (where stereo duplex is selected as parameter), so I can't select it as a sound input.
I precise that the microphone was working under Microsoft Windows Vista.
I tried other input parameters in pulseaudio but none make apears the internal microphone in the list.
I also tried to modify the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf with :
options snd-hda-intel model=targa-dig

and also
options snd-hda-intel model=targa-8ch-dig

and also
options snd-hda-intel model=auto probe_mask=1

None of them worked...
It is like if the internal microphone was disconnected, I have check and it is well plugged.
I have activated everything in the alsamixer interface :
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.2.9 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   Carte : HDA Intel                                                                               F1 :  Aide                 │
│    Puce : Realtek ALC1200                                                                         F2 :  Informations système │
│     Vue : F3: Lecture  F4:[Capture] F5: Tout                                                      F6 :  Choisir la carte son │
│ Élement : Line Boost [gain dB : 20,00, 20,00]                                                     Esc : quitter              │
│                                                                                                                              │
│                                                                                                                              │
│                       ┌──┐           ┌──┐           ┌──┐           ┌──┐                                                      │
│                       │  │           │  │           │  │           │  │                                                      │
│                       │  │           │  │           │  │           │  │                                                      │
│                       │  │           │  │           │  │           │  │                                                      │
│                       │  │           │  │           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │  │           │  │           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │  │           │  │           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │  │           │  │           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│           │▒▒│                                                      │
│                       └──┘           └──┘          G└──┘D         G└──┘D          Mic            Mic                         │
│                                                   CAPTURE        CAPTURE                                                     │
│                      53<>53         53<>53         81<>81         81<>81                                                     │
│                 <  Line Boost  >  Mic Boost       Capture       Capture 1     Input Source  Input Source 1                   │
│                                                                                                                              │
│                                                                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


Here is the proc asound pcm :
yvette@yvette-EX620:~$ cat /proc/asound/pcm 
00-00: ALC1200 Analog : ALC1200 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
00-01: ALC1200 Digital : ALC1200 Digital : playback 1
00-02: ALC1200 Alt Analog : ALC1200 Alt Analog : capture 1
01-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
yvette@yvette-EX620:~$ 

Also something is bothering me about the chip : Ubuntu detect an ALC1200 but I have learn by MSI brand after-sales that on this computer it is an ALC888S (Spec : Azalia interface, ALC 888S; Analog 7.1 (4 Audio Jack) & SPDIF)
If anyone has an idea that I could try...
Thanking you in advance,
